# Pass large data values without POST in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I m in a situation where i need to pass a larger number of values but without using POST

I can not use POST because when clicked on Browser back button sometime I get 'Webpage has expired'.

To overcome this i took help of Cookies like this

```
  AppFrame.setCookie("EmailInvoiceIds", ids.join(','), 1);
  window.location = "?isEmail=true&eid=1&template=2+"/#/customer/email";
```

Then in other Jquery i get cookies data like this

```
 var emailInvoiceIds = AppFrame.getCookie("EmailInvoiceIds");
```

but this get flopped when data size increases 4K limit of cookie

So is there any other way i can pass large data values without using POST

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use either "GET" or "POST". There is no other option in HTTP protocol. Since the request hold bigger data length, I would suggest go with "POST" only. "Page expire" is happening to avoid posting duplicate data. And you can avoid it, making your post operation by using AJAX instead of form submission.

Comment: Thanks for you reply...but AJAX POST just post, i want to redirect to that page as well...i need that large data on that page..

Comment: You have to do set `location.href = <someurl>` in success callback of ajax. Alternatively you can use `location.replace(<someurl>)`.

Comment: And to populate data on destination page, read the posted data(which is stored in database) from database and generate page for `<someurl>`. Hopefully I am making sense.

Comment: see i have a grid with 1000 records, selecting all, generate a large list if ids, need to send to another url which use those ids to generate another list of records...so i need this ids on that page to which i m redirecting...

Comment: can i use some session variable in jquery?

Comment: Yes, you can use session variable if those ids information are not require after current session closed.

Comment: yes i do not require those after current session closed.. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Deleting session information happens automatically based on settings in php.ini file.

Comment: There is global session cookie which is indicate to PHP(any server side scripting) about current browser session. If you are store information in session storage of PHP, this will be deleted by PHP after the expiration. This expiration period is calculated from settings of php.ini. There is no need to handle such a information in JS level, except some special cases like "force the user to logout".

Comment: @AnilD, Good Pick. And I just want to clear something about plugin. Since the plugin uses session Storage, the plugin needs HTML5. And to support lower Browser version there is an internal fallback to cookie. That is, plugin stores all the information to cookie. And here, be sure the following things. At any cause once the information stored in cookie, that will send to server as a part of request header as long as the value live in cookie storage.